# Using regex to detect twitter handles

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to use regex to detect twitter mentions. The example message is, "@This_matches hello there, @doesnt@match how is it going @matches"

What i am using:

```
m_list = re.findall(r'(?<!\w)(@\w{1,15})(?=\s)' ,a)
```

The only issue i am having is that when the username is at the end of the string it will not pick it up. For example: "@testing blah" works, "blah @testing2" does not work. So when there is no character at the end of the string it will not match. How do i fix this?

Comment: Note that the Twitter API already extracts mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m_list = re.findall(r'(?<!\w)(@\w{1,15})(?=\s|$)' ,a)

                                             ^^
```

Add `$ assert position at end of a line`

or simply

```
m_list = re.findall(r'(?<!\w)(@\w{1,15})\b' ,a)

                                        ^^
```

`\b word boundary`

Comment: Your first part of the answer seems to be working quite well! Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, i will in a second, i have one more issue. `(?<!\w)(@\w{1,15})(?=\s|$)` is failing when it is given @@foo. I do not want @@foo to work. Because it is detecting just the last part @foo from the whole @@foo. How do i not match when there is another '@' behind the @

Comment: @Armageddon80 `(?<!\w)(?<!@)(@\w{1,15})(?=\s|$)` or simply `(?<![\w@])(@\w{1,15})(?=\s|$)`

Answer (score 0):

You may replace the last positive lookahead with negative lookahead.

```
m_list = re.findall(r'(?<!\w)(@\w{1,15})(?!\S)' ,a)
```